# How to subtract in R Programming Language

Tags: r

Here is my syntax:

```
a <-as.integer(a)
a <-readline(prompt = "Enter first number: ")
b <-as.integer(b)
b <-readline(prompt = "Enter second number: ")
c = a-b
print(paste("Difference of two number is :",c)
```

and the output is this:

> print(paste("Difference of two number is :",c))
> Error in paste("Difference of two number is :", c) :
> cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'

can someone explain to me what is the error and help me this my first time learning r language

Comment: Looks like the `readline` lines should come before the ones converting their output to an integer. And you need another closing `)` to match the two opening parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

- the first issue is that you should cast a and b as numerics *after* you input them
- the second issue that that value assignment in R uses `<-` rather that `=`
- **edit:** As mentioned in the comments: `=` does work in place of `<-`, but there is just a preference for `<-`

The following code will work :-)

```
a <-readline(prompt = "Enter first number: ")
a <-as.integer(a)
b <-readline(prompt = "Enter second number: ")
b <-as.integer(b)
c <- a-b
print(paste("Difference of two number is :", c))
```

Comment: To be fair, `=` works just fine. It's just that [`<-` is preferred](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/09/why-do-we-use-arrow-as-an-assignment-operator/) for different reasons (good or bad).